# Getting WordPress Permalinks to play nice with Nginx

Tags: nginx, wordpress, permalinks

I'm running an Nginx server with multiple WordPress installs in subdirectories, for instance:

> /var/www/lovelyfolder

I had assumed, perhaps naively, that the following code (in default.conf) would apply to all subfolders in the root:

```
        location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
```

BUT, in order to get permalinks to work for the specific WordPress install in that folder I have to add the following:

```
        location /lovelyfolder/ {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /lovelyfolder/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
```

Is there a way of altering the first code so that it automatically applies to all new and existing subdirectories, or am I stuck having to manually add the above for each individual subdirectory?

Comment: You'll need a separate `location` for each WP install.

Comment: Bugger... That's a pain!

Ah well! Just thought I'd check there was no way of doing this automatically, or defining the root recursively. 

Thanks @MichaelHampton!

Comment: You probably ought to be using Multisite.

Comment: Too many incompatibilities in terms of plugins - at least for the moment! It's something I may look into in future. 

Thanks for your help! :)